How to configure aws-sam template file to grant access in nested routes available on application
first of all sorry by my English, Google's help me =D.
I created a NestJS application that exposes a swagger ui in the / route and 2 other routes (/api/export and /api/export/{exportName}). My application runs without problems when I launch it through the default initialization from NestJS but when I compile it to use in a lambda function I can only access the swagger route with the template below:
# <rootDir>/template.yml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  ExampleFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: dist/main.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        Base:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET
        Proxy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: GET
    DependsOn:
      - ExampleFunctionLogGroup
  ExampleFunctionLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub '/aws/lambda/${ExampleFunction}'
      RetentionInDays: 7
Outputs:
  Example:
    Description: 'Example function'
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/'

The project contains this minimal structure:
/src:
 | - app.controller.ts
 | - app.module.ts
 | - boostrap.ts
 | - main.ts
 | - lambda.ts

Where app.controller.ts and app.module.ts are the initial files created when initializing a nest application and the other files are replicated below:
// <rootDir>/src/bootstrap.ts
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import * as packageJson from '../package.json';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

export async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {bufferLogs: true});
  app.enableCors();

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle(packageJson.displayName)
    .setDescription(packageJson.description)
    .setVersion(packageJson.version)
    .setContact(packageJson.author.name, packageJson.author.url, packageJson.author.email)
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('', app, document, {
    customCssUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.17.14/swagger-ui.min.css',
    customJs: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.17.14/swagger-ui.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.17.14/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/5.17.14/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
    ],
  });

  return app;
}

// <rootDir>/src/main.ts
import {bootstrap} from './bootstrap';

bootstrap()
  .then(app => app.listen(3000))
  .then(() => console.log(`run on port 3000`));

// <rootDir>/src/lambda.ts
import {Handler} from 'aws-lambda';
import serverless from 'serverless-http';
import {bootstrap} from './bootstrap';

let cachedHandler: Handler;

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (!cachedHandler) {
    const app = await bootstrap();
    cachedHandler = serverless(app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance());
  }
  return cachedHandler(event, context, callback);
};

How should I configure the template.yml file so that I can expose swagger's dependencies and also all other routes since clearly the problem is in the configuration of this file which I don't understand
